# Is there a way to use dynamic link libraries in UEFI?

Tags: uefi, edk2

We are developing UEFI Application using EDK2.

I need to use a library with LGPL-3.0 license, but our source code cannot be made public.
(Of course, the library can be modified, and the modified parts will be made public.)

In this case, how can I implement and use the dynamic library in UEFI?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a driver (and make it public) that wraps the LGPL code and make it accessible via a protocol that you define.

Use it from your UEFI Application like any other UEFI driver.